# What are the best practices to safely store OAuth2 tokens in a database?

Tags: session-management, defense, storage

I'm building a website with Patreon integration and I have identified the need to store Patreon user's OAuth2 token in the database. I'm wondering what's the best way to do that, security-wise. Some considerations:

- The token doesn't give vast access, just read-only information about the Patreon user. Still, there might be some marginally-sensitive information there, like real name, email address, campaigns that they've pledged money to and the amounts, etc.
- The token will only be used by back-end processes.
- The token expires in 1 month, so I also need to store a refresh token and refresh it periodically with a scheduled task
- For the foreseeable future, all the code will live in a single managed virtual server. That includes the webserver, the cronjob, any configuration, etc. I don't even have full root access to the server - it's managed by CloudWays.

I could encrypt all those tokens with some key, but said key would still live quite close to the data itself, so it feels like I wouldn't be gaining much security. Perhaps I shouldn't bother?

Comment: What DB are you using, and is it also hosted on the webserver (and if so as the same user or a different one) or in some other provider?

Comment: @CBHacking MariaDB. And, as I said, EVERYTHING lives right next to each other on the same server. There's some regular Linux permissions protecting things, but nothing else - there aren't even any containers.

Comment: You said "all the code", which typically means your application and its framework, HTTP listener, maintenance scripts, etc, but not usually your database; if you'd actually said "everything" I'd have predicted that meant DB too. In any case, since you mention Linux permissions, does that mean the DB is in fact running as a different user than the webserver? If so, you still have somewhere to store the key that the webserver can read but the DB server can't.

Comment: @CBHacking - Ooops. Yes, my apologies, I miswrote. I did mean "everything", not just code. And by "managed" I meant that Cloudways has full access to it while I can only poke around in a few places they allow me to. But I could make a file that the webserver can read and the DB server can't. I had thought of that too, but I had some doubts - what attack would it be that would allow the attacker to gain access to the DB, but not the webserver? Doesn't it usually happen the other way around - the attacker first compromises the code and from there gains access to the DB?

Comment: See my answer below, but there are some attacks that hit the DB directly. SQL injection is the obvious one (and it's very bad regardless, but _slightly_ less bad if the sensitive data are encrypted) but DB backups also have a tendency to leak (left on an unsecured S3 bucket or other cloud store, backup tapes stolen from a technician's car, decommissioned hard drive that wasn't erased properly... though of course if the DB is on the same machine and same storage as the webserver, there's a risk that the backup contains both the DB and the webserver including the key file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting sensitive data (or even *all* data, though the practicality of that depends on a number of factors) at rest is a good practice. There's almost certainly *somewhere* you can store the key such that an attacker who compromises only the DB wouldn't be able to read the encrypted data. Even if that's literally just in a file deployed along with your server code (obviously, don't let the key file be requested through the web server...). An attacker who gains code execution on the server - or even just SSRF that allows `file:` URIs - will not be stopped by this, but there's nothing you can really do about that anyhow; the server has to be able to decrypt, so anybody running malicious code *as* the server can decrypt too. However, somebody who compromises *only the DB* (via a stolen backup, or SQL injection, or brute-forcing the DB login that you accidentally exposed to the Internet, or whatever) will be thwarted; the key is in another server.

Ideally, you should run the database separately from the webserver (different logical host at least, ideally different physical one and maybe even different service), as the more separation you get between DB and key, the less likely both will be compromised together. Obviously you know your needs and costs better than I could, but in your place I'd consider something like hosting the server on EC2, and the DB on RDS (those are AWS services; there are equivalents in all the big IAAS platforms). That would even let you store the key in yet a third place - KMS or secret storage - such that it need not exist on the disk of either service. However, if you're set on hosting everything within one machine, running the servers as different users and keeping each one's files hidden from the other is still better than not doing that.